# Is there a way to find a whether a string in one database table is a substring of another string in a different table of the same database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL as my DBMS.
I have a database called **studentinfo** with two tables, namely: **students** and **allstudents**.
Each of these tables has a column named **fullName**.
My objective is to determine whether the **name** value in the **students** table is a substring of the **name** value in the **allstudents** table.
Any help accorded is highly appreciated.

Comment: INSTR() or LOCATE() functions. LIKE operator.

Comment: you can use `INNER JOIN ... ON LIKE` too. Anything you've tried?

Comment: This is what I wrote and it is throwing an error: `SELECT fullName FROM allstudents
   where fullName LIKE CONCAT('%',SELECT fullName FROM students , '%');`